# How to get data in a tensor with some coordinates effeciently?

Tags: pytorch

There is a `5`-dimensional tensor `dense_volume1` and I have many `4`-dimensional index tensors `coord` inside of 'coords'.

How can I index the original value tensor efficiently?

The code below seems too slow:

```
for coord in coords:
    feats.append(dense_volume1[coord[3], :, coord[0], coord[1], coord[2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Programmatically indexing with `coord`

You can permute the axes of `dense_volume1` such that you are able to index with sequential dimensions from `coord`. In other words, by building a tensor `dv` such that:

```
dense_volume1[coord[3], :, coord[0], coord[1], coord[2]]
```

Is equal to

```
dv[coord[0], coord[1], coord[2], coord[3], :] # trailing ':' is not necessary
```

You can do so with [`torch.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html):

```
>>> dv = dense_volume1.permute(2,3,4,0,1) # the returned tensor is a view
```

Then you can simply index with coord by splitting its first axis:

```
>>> for coord in coords:
...    feats.append(dv[tuple(coord)])
```